# Python interpolate from csv file

Tags: python, csv, interpolation

I am trying to interpolate data from a csv file. The first 2 columns are the same size. I had success with same data in txt files before, this is my first attempt with a csv file. Any help would be appreciated.
Sample csv file

```
wave,transmittance
406.06,0.384
420.06,0.398
440.85,0.416
....,.....
```

```
import numpy as np
import csv
from scipy import interpolate

# column 0  wavelength
# column 1  transmittance
# .....

with open('CCD.csv','r') as csv_file:
    next(csv_file)
    data = list(csv.reader(csv_file))

x=[column[0] for column in data]
y=[column[1] for column in data]

I = interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(x, y)


print(x)
```

```
Output:
UFuncTypeError                 
<ipython-input-9-fa767336938e> in <module>
     12 y=[column[1] for column in data]
     13 
---> 14 I = interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(x, y)

UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'subtract' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U11'), dtype('<U11')) -> dtype('<U11')
```

EDITED :

```
with open('CCD.csv','r') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    next(csv_file)  # discard header
    data = list(reader)
x1=[column[0] for column in data]
y1=[column[1] for column in data]

I2 = interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(x1, y1)
z2 = I2(550)
print(z2)
```

```
UFuncTypeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-a8127aad6fce> in <module>
      6 y1=[column[1] for column in data]
      7 
----> 8 I2 = interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(x1, y1)
      9 z2 = I2(550)
     10 print(z2)

UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'subtract' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U11'), dtype('<U11')) -> dtype('<U11')
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post an example of your CSV file, *as formatted text, not an image*.

Comment: I posted an example of the CSV file. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close. You need to create the reader object when you first open the file, *then* use the reader to iterate your rows:

```py
import csv

data = None
with open('CCD.csv', newline='') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    next(csv_file)  # discard header
    data = list(reader)

x1 = [float(row[0]) for row in data]
y1 = [float(row[1]) for row in data]

print(x1)
print(y1)
```

and I get:

```py
[406.06, 420.06, 440.85]
[0.384, 0.398, 0.416]
```

I can see how you got that, though, just coming from iterating text files line-by-line.  Good try! :)

Also, you don't need to specify read-mode `'r'`, that's the default; but for CSV files, it's recommended that in most cases, you want `newline=''` so that Python leaves all newline chars (NL, LF, CRLF) as is for the CSV reader to deal with, according the CSV spec.

Alternatively, you can build `x` and `y` while you're reading the CSV:

```py
x, y = [], []
with open('CCD.csv', newline='') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    next(csv_file)  # discard header
    
    for row in reader:
        x.append(float(row[0]))
        y.append(float(row[1]))

print(x)
print(y)
```

Same results from the prints from above.

Comment: Thank you, I've tried it like that but still doesn't work.

Comment: I just ran that on your small sample CSV, and `data` looks right to me. What are you seeing?

Comment: Oh, I've focused on just getting the CSV reader to work for you, which it does. Now, you need to convert all the string values in `data` to `float` when you're iterating your x's and y's.

Comment: Yes it works. Had to convert to float!! Jeez, I didn't think the data was string formatted in csv. Thanks a lot. Learn something new every day

Comment: Well, it's always a string in a CSV file (which is just a text file with *convention*). Yeah, Pandas does a lot for you. :) Please give this an upvote if you found it valuable. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is how I managed it with pandas, but I am still curious about the alternative way, without pandas

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('CCD.csv')

x = df['KAF16200wave'].to_numpy()
y = df['KAF16200transmitence'].to_numpy()

I = interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(x, y)

z = I(550)
print("QE:",z)
```

```
QE: 0.589681398010309
```

Comment: Where does `KAF16200` come from, in the column names? Is that some special Pandas syntax?

Comment: Yes, column name